# Identificar Navegador - Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Necessito saber quando o usuário acessar o website através do Internet Explorer, executar um CSS.
Até ai tudo bem, segue o código que utilizei para aplicar o CSS:

```
 <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/template/css/apenas-ie.css" />
 <![endif]-->
```

Porém não está funcionando, infelizmente não está identificando se é Internet Explorer ou não, pois se aplico o css na folha de rosto padrão pega, mas dentro desta não.

Alguém possui algum Script para verificar se o navegador é Internet Explorer, indiferente da versão, para eu poder então fazer um if e aplicar o css?
Obs: Necessito disso em Javascript.

Comment: Consideras o Microsoft Edge também como Internet Explorer?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9atsffau/

Comment: @Sergio somente Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feito.
Segue código de identificação:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
if(isIE == true){
    var ie = ' <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/template/css/apenas-ie.css">';
}else{
     var ie = '';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe detector seu navegador para entender sobre @media

Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
<link rel="styleSheet" href="./teste-ie.css"/>
<link rel="styleSheet" href="./teste-chrome.css" media="screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)" />
<link rel="styleSheet" href="./teste-firefox.css" media="screen and (-moz-images-in-menus:0)" />
```

ou

```
<style type="text/css">
/* Outros navegadores */
body {
    background: cyan;
}

/* Webkit (Chrome e Safari) */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    body {
        background: darkseagreen;
    }
}

/* Mozilla Firefox */
@media screen and (-moz-images-in-menus:0) {
    body {
        background: gold;
    }
}
</style>
```

Não tem regra IE é um padrão de Microsoft deixa sem valor media ou veja abaixo:
http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.org/css_hacks.html (tem outro jeito para ver)